# Material UI Styles Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styling, codesandbox

Im attempting to build a website using Material-UI and React. When attempting to use Material-UI's styling via the Hook API, it works online in codesandbox.io but does not work locally when I run it. The border radius property does not seem to update, nor do any of the properties in the button or instruction object

[image: What I see when I run the same code locally]

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  button: {
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 100,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: 2,
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return 'Select campaign settings...';
    case 1:
      return 'What is an ad group anyways?';
    case 2:
      return 'This is the bit I really care about!';
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

function HorizontalLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const steps = getSteps();

  function isStepOptional(step) {
    return step === 1;
  }

  function isStepSkipped(step) {
    return skipped.has(step);
  }

  function handleNext() {
    let newSkipped = skipped;
    if (isStepSkipped(activeStep)) {
      newSkipped = new Set(newSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.delete(activeStep);
    }

    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(newSkipped);
  }

  function handleBack() {
    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep - 1);
  }

  function handleSkip() {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
      // You probably want to guard against something like this,
      // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
      throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped(prevSkipped => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  }

  function handleReset() {
    setActiveStep(0);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const labelProps = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            labelProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
      <div>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
            </Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
              Reset
            </Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>
            <div>
              <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                Back
              </Button>
              {isStepOptional(activeStep) && (
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleSkip}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  Skip
                </Button>
              )}
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleNext}
                className={classes.button}
              >
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HorizontalLinearStepper;
```

You can view the expected results here: https://98m6j7m314.codesandbox.io
in which the buttons border is circular after applying the borderRadius property

Comment: In inspect element is the style being overwritten by something else or is it not getting rendered at all ?

Comment: @Muljayan it seems like its being overwritten, but im not too sure, it has a class associated with it by the name of .MuiButton-root-107 and that class is setting the border radius to 4px. This is not the same on the working version although it is the same code and package versions

Comment: Did you try on different browsers ? Also try using the !important tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@material-ui/styles` with `@material-ui/core` you need to follow the installation step https://v3.material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#migration-for-material-ui-core-users.

Here's your codesandbox link working: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rv2w1

Comment: Hello Josh, thank you very much, I did not perform the installation step correctly! It now works after importing the bootstrap.js, although I had imported the install from @material-ui/styles, but it was below the import of React

Comment: @aswiftproduction Can you plz share how do imported bootstrap.js to index.js file?

Comment: @Oshik, what's the point of importing styles if you then still need to make styles?

Comment: Codesandbox is not working. That is why we request always to add code example in the answer along with the link.

Comment: @Josh Wooding My app won't compile following this with error = Attempted import error: 'install' is not exported from '@material-ui/styles'. Any idea why this would occur?

Comment: @CGermain If you are using v4 the install step is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers use cache and in some cases your changes are not reloaded. Refershing using Ctrl+f5, clearing or disabling cache in your settings may be useful.

Please attempt to see your localhost web page using another web browser & in incognito

Comment: hey my friend, just tried the incognito, it still doesn't render the Button with the borderRadius, ill try the ctrl-f5

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very simple answer for this -

You just need to change the Injection Order of MUI CSS.
Check the website for the solution

https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order-3

It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).