# Material-UI production build generate different styles order definition than in development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, parceljs

Using material-ui, the production build differs from the development one: the generated material-ui styles in production are not defined in the same order as ones from development one.

In **DEV**, the HTML `head` tag contains the material-ui styles in this order:

- MuiPaper
- MuiTouchRipple
- MuiButtonBase
- MuiButton
- [...]

In **PROD**, the HTML `head` tag contains the material-ui styles in this order:

- MuiButton
- MuiButtonBase
- MuiIcon
- MuiMenu
- [...]

So in production, it breaks styles: material-ui own styles are overriding one another...

Some more context:

- Material-ui is used in version 4.11.3
- Parcel is used to make the production build
- Custom `makeStyles` are **not used** (so I am not concerned by the https://stackoverflow.com/a/62646041/3790208 solution)
- I tried without success the solution described here: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-arent-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds => I created a single `generateClassName` instance and passed it to the `StylesProvider` used on top the component tree (this solution had no effect)
- @material-ui/styles is **not used**

My question: how can I make sure material-ui styles are rendered the same way in development and in production ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually to upgrade to the v5 of Material-ui: https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/

The root issue seemed to be related to Material-ui v4 not correctly handling tree-shaking: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16609

Comment: not sure if this one is similar issue as this thread, but could you take a look on my issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73796415/production-build-always-put-mui-css-at-the-top, I'm already using mui v5