# Production build always put MUI CSS at the top

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Could someone give me some insights about this.
Overriding Material UI CSS works in development environment,
but then it swapped in production environment.

[image: Production build]

This one is wrong, Material UI css should be at the bottom

[image: Development build]

This one is right, I'm overriding Material UI css.

Comment: Have you already tried to have a look at https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/ ?

Comment: I added `StyledEngineProvider injectFirst` before, but it doesnt solve the production issue @amanteaux

Comment: can you provide some of your styles?