# SSR + Material UI Drawer + webpack production build broken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to use material UI SSR example that given by Material-UI ([Link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/ssr)) It worked. Then I tried to integrate Material-UI Drawer in this example, I used Persistent drawer example code that given by Material UI ([Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/deopk?file=/demo.js)). I copied demo.js file from [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/deopk?file=/demo.js)

**This is my Demo.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginRight: drawerWidth,
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginRight: -drawerWidth,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginRight: 0,
  },
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerRight() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap className={classes.title}>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="end"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            className={clsx(open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
          facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit
          gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id
          donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit
          adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras.
          Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo quis
          imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. At augue eget
          arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem
          donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
          facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
          tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
          consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed
          vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. In
          hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et
          tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin
          nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas
          accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </main>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="right"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I changed App.js file just like this

```
 import React from 'react';
    import Demo from './demo'
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <Demo />
      );
    }
```

everything worked in development build

then I changed webpack mode to production

mode: 'production',

Material UI broken after I changing mode from development to production

[image]
I followed this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62646041/9713119) to fix this issue but issue not fixed

Here I have added my **webpack configuration**

```
    const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './client.js',
  mode:  'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**Here I have attached a screenshot with my code structure and client.js file**
[image]

Comment: Can you share your Webpack configuration and the screenshot of development?

Comment: Please share more detail, about your SSR configuration and Webpack definition.

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply I have added my webpack configuration file

Comment: @AmerllicA I used this sample https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/ssr and copied Demo.js file from here https://codesandbox.io/s/ljr2o?file=/demo.js:0-6570

Comment: @SonuBamniya I added additional information please let me know it's enough to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing mode to "production" makes you bundle compile in production mode but doesn't make you server run in production mode. `makeStyles` function generates different (i.e shorter) class names for production. So your styles (generated on client) and html (generate on the server) have different class names.

To run the server in production mode use `npm run-script production`

But when you actually going to run it in production you want to build the app, that's going to create bundle and `server.js` file and then run it with tool like `pm2`. More on that here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

`npm run-script production` sets NODE_ENV environtment variable to production value which makes server to run in production mode see the package.json config

[image]

Comment: I will try this answer and let you know, thanks!

Comment: It worked, Thanks. I am using firebase cloud function. First run facing the same design issue after click event it worked well. But default npm run works well even in a first run

Comment: npm run-script production sets NODE_ENV to production which makes server run in production mode. It's iportant to run the same mode for client and server. I'll add some details in the answer

Comment: Ok, Your answer worked well.  I will try the same way for cloud functions too. Thanks

Comment: Working in firebase deployment too. Thanks :-)