# Material-UI - why different css is shown on prod environment then development env

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, development-environment, production-environment

I use material UI (`verison: ^4.12.3`) Select, with custom input.

For some reason the prod env Select input has a black background and `:before` element with white background.

I don't know from where it comes from.

this is image of the prod:

[image: prod env Select]

this is image of the dev Select:

[image: dev env Select]

when comparing the 2 css & html of the envs Select element, it's is shown that there is a `::before` element added in prod that is not presented in dev

[image: html & css comparison]

also, the background color is different. in prod there is another class added to the InputBase element, which doesn't exist in dev. this class adds a background-color black:

[image: added css class]

**Edit 1**

it seems like MUI inject `<style>`. in the prod html i see the `background-color: black` and the `::before`. ill try adding the index solution, but my problem is not precedence (the style that i do use override the injected style). also, it wont help the `::before`  element. how to disable the injected styles ? or work around it ?

the injected bad css:

[image: injected style]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `<StylesProvider />` wrapper to the app fixed it. we use micro-frontend infrastructure. and one of the frontends app also had `makeStyles`. this is causing classNames conflicts in MUI.

in the root component `<App/>`:

```
import {
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  seed: 'app1'
});

const App = () => {
 return (
    <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
       <OtherAppComponents />
    </StylesProvider>
)
}
```

**if you have more then 2 add a provider and a generator to each, with different seed**

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473898/material-ui-rendering-bugs-in-production-build/62646041#62646041). As answered by user [Mordechai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751640/mordechai).

It seems like webpack could mess with MUI's rules on JSS precedence... This could be solved by adding an index of one to MUI's methods.

```
//Hook
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    // your styles here
}, {index: 1})

// HOC 
MyComponent = withStyles({
    // your styles here
}, {index: 1})(MyComponent)
```

Comment: thx for your response. can you please check Edit-1 i answer your question there.

Comment: Before we start digging into your code, please check out https://mui.com/getting-started/faq/#why-arent-my-components-rendering-correctly-in-production-builds