# Heroku Deployment Removes Material UI makeStyles?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, material-ui, classname, makestyles

It appears that Heroku deployment is removing all of my calls to my MUI makeStyles doc and is subsequently breaking a good amount of my app's appearance. Looking for any wisdom on this before I go back and do all my styling in-line (tested it - this DOES WORK).

Everything looks perfectly fine on my localhost view.

Example screenshot of the difference (disregard the username difference) -

[image: makestyles not present on Heroku instance]

Here's a snipped from my styles.jsx (I chopped it way down to make this code reasonable in length, but there is a ton more):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  //-------------Disclaimer.jsx-------------//

  disclaimer: {
    textAlign: "center",
    paddingTop: "20px",
    backgroundSize: "70",
    backgroundPosition: "30% 40%",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  },
  Button: {
    marginTop: "40px",
    paddingTop: "40px",
  },


}));

export default useStyles;
```

...and in every component I have:

`import useStyles from "../components/styles/styles";`

...and:

`const classes = useStyles();`

...and, again, it works great on my localhost.

There are no errors related to this in my terminal when I push to Heroku.

I changed one piece from calling `className={classes.CLASSNAMEHERE}` to styling inline with `style={{style: "style"}}` and it fixed it.

I hope this sums the issue up. Please forgive me if I have not done this post exactly how is expected - I am rather new. I was hoping this was a common issue but I can't anything on it! The only thing I DID find was a suggestion that I add a `--save` to my MUI install and that did not do the trick.

Thanks so much in advance, everyone!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62473898

Comment: @NearHuscarl that appears to be breaking everything in my dev build just like it appears on Heroku - perhaps that's a step in the right direction somehow? Forgive me for being a bit daft at this - I'm relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution was to add an index of 1 to take precedence over JSS styles.

I also had to chop that arrow function.

Thus:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({

  disclaimer: {
    textAlign: "center",
    paddingTop: "20px",
    backgroundSize: "70",
    backgroundPosition: "30% 40%",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  },

    //--------------------------
    //------styling continued...
    //--------------------------

}));

export default useStyles;
```

...BECAME:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({  //removed arrow function

  disclaimer: {
    textAlign: "center",
    paddingTop: "20px",
    backgroundSize: "70",
    backgroundPosition: "30% 40%",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  },

    //--------------------------
    //------styling continued...
    //--------------------------

}, {index: 1});     //added index 1

export default useStyles;
```

The arrow function was breaking the appearance on my localhost.

Alternatively, as I was about to do, you could go through and style everything in-line or use traditional CSS. No thanks!